# Is there a way to output users name as a link to profile in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, profile, pathauto

Im using pathauto so user profiles have a clean URL in the format /user/name-name

How can I output the users name as a link to the profile? Ive seen the theme() function used to do stuff similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the l() function to create the link and make the link to user/uid. When using l, it will be converted to whatever you set it up to in pathauto.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user's name as the text of the link, use `theme('username', $account);` where $account is the fully-loaded user object from user_load().